# How do I get the Virtual Machines folder on Win7?

Tags: c#, windows-7, virtual-pc, special-folders, xp-mode

I'm writing a tool called [XP-More](http://xpmore.codeplex.com), which should help manage Windows 7 Virtual Machines. The first thing the tool has to do when launched is find the VM folder. However, turns out that folder is not listed as a Windows Special Folder. I use a workaround, but it's unreliable. Ideally,

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.VMFolder)
```

or so would have done the job, but VMFolder is a fiction of my imagination. Is there any real way to get that folder?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/post/VirtualPC-Default-Folder.aspx). You can either get the default folder, or search for the 'myvirtualmachines' environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

@m0sa - your solution works for **Microsoft Virtual PC**, but Windows 7 comes with a variant called **Windows Virtual PC**, which seems to be slightly different. On my Windows 7, for instance, there's neither *myvirtualmachines* environment variable nor any other one pointing to the actual folder.

(sorry for writing this as an answer. I know it sucks, but I can't add comments at this point)